# When to use '.' or '#' before selectors in jquery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

Sometimes we need to use '.' and '#' with selectors in jquery, but sometimes we have to write the names of selectors without these symbols.
Example: `$('.article').removeClass('current');`
Here we used '.' with 'article' but not with 'current'.
I don't understand the difference between the two cases.When should we use them and when not?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing out a selector, as in the `$('.article')` part, you need to have a way of differentiating between the various methods of selecting an element.  So if you are looking for an element with a particular class name, you indicate that with the '.' prefix.  If you are looking for an element with a particular id, you indicate that with the '#' prefix.  If you are looking for a particular element type, you don't use any prefix.  The `$()` needs to be able to handle all three of those cases (class, id, element type), so you need to use the prefixes to indicate what you are looking for.  The `removeClass()` function already knows you are giving it a class name, not a selector, so you don't need to use a '.' prefix.  Similarly the `getElementById()` function doesn't need a '#' prefix because it already knows you are specifying the id.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: In a jQuery **selector**, `.` indicates a *class name*, and `#` indicates an *id*. When not referring to them as part of a **selector** (e.g., in the `removeClass()` function), then you don't use those prefixes.

Long answer: Read about [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) in general. It will be time well spent.